# wrap an IMG in a link in each div

Tags: jquery, html

I need to wrap an `img` in a link in each `div`. The problem I am facing is that the same image is wrapped in each `div`. I need to wrap the specific `img` in the specific link of each `div`.

CODE I am using:

```
$("div.level_1").each(function() {
    $("a.lightview").wrapInner($("img.euImg"));
});
```

STARTING CODE:

```
<div class="level_1 euItem group3 generation_y _2012">
    <img border="0" src="img1.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/run.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'">
            <span>Run</span>
        </a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem group3 generation_y _2012">
    <img border="0" src="img2.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/bike.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'">
            <span>Run</span>
        </a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

RESULT CODE NEEDED:

```
<div class="level_1 euItem group3 generation_y _2012">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/run.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'">
            <img border="0" src="img1.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
        </a>
    </h4>
    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem group3 generation_y _2012">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/bike.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'">
            <img border="0" src="img2.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
        </a>
    </h4>
    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the element:

```
$("div.level_1 img").each(function() {
   $(this).next('h4').find('a').empty().append(this);
   // $(this).next('h4').find('span').replaceWith(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("div.level_1").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a.lightview").empty().wrapInner($(this).find("img.euImg"));
});
```

Notice the use of `this` to refer to the div within the `each` function call.

I also added `empty()` to clear the span out of the anchor element, as that's not shown in the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.level_1').each(function () {
    var $div = $(this);
    var $img = $div.find('img.euImg');
    var $span = $div.find('a.lightview span');

    $span.replaceWith($img);
});
```

It could all be compressed a little, but hopefully this way it's quite clear what it's doing. Sticking it all together and doing it in one hit:

```
$('div.level_1').each(function () {
    $(this).find('a.lightview').empty().append($(this).find('img.euImg'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selectors you're using aren't specific enough. The code, as it is will select the first `a` element in the document with the class `lightview` and wrap it around the first `img` with class `euImg` in the document.

If I'm not mistaken, what you're trying to do is apply those operations to the children of each respective div. Try this instead:

```
var img;
$('div.level_1').each(function() {
    img = $(this).children('img.euImg').detach();
    $(this).find('a.lightview').wrapInner(img);
});
```

The `detach()` is necessary in order to remove the element so you don't get copies.
See the documentation on [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/).